# Count value and create next column how much time is is repeated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe consist of 2 columns. UCC and year. I want to count each UCC how much time it is repeated and give the o/p is in next column.
Data:
UCC     year
23.     2018
23.    2019
23.    2020
23.    2021
23.    2022
24.    2021
24.    2015
25.    2011
27.    2018
27.    2019
I want output in the format
UCC year      countif
23.     2018.    5
23.      2019.   4
23.      2020.   3
.....

Comment: Have you tried Counter from collections?? `from colections import counter`. `counter(dataframe[colum])`